# How to create a python code to convert all las files in user defined folder into respective excel file using las2excelbulk function

Tags: python, excel, log-ascii-standard

I have to convert `.las` files in one directory to `.xlsx` files using `las2excelbulk` function.

Currently I can do that in command prompt but I want to do it using Python: is it possible?

Here's the link which i referred https://lasio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exporting.html

- Open CMD
- switch to the folder having las files using " cd
- las2excelbulk -r -i

The file would be converted.

```
# this is working for only one file

import lasio

las = lasio.read('*.las')

las.to_excel('testsamplelas.xlsx')
```

Comment: Command-line arguments are passed to scripts as a list of strings in `sys.argv`, so your script can look there for arguments. You can determine the current-working-directory by calling `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `lasio.read()` can only be a single filename, but you can use the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) and [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) modules in the Python standard library to step through all .las files recursively.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import lasio

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("your_directory"):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.las'):
        path = os.path.join(root, filename)
        las = lasio.read(path, ignore_header_errors=True)
        las.to_excel(path + ".xlsx")
```

`lasio.read(..., ignore_header_errors=True)` is the equivalent of `las2excelbulk -i`.

It may also be useful to inspect [the code behind](https://github.com/kinverarity1/lasio/blob/5187f4fd1f05baaea1117764729b3d9a1d77aa7a/lasio/excel.py#L119-L138) the `las2excelbulk` command line tool for more information.

Comment: I tested your solution but keep coming up with the following error: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'P-129_out.LAS'" however when I test the .las with lasio, and simply read to do a single file conversion to a csv, there are no problems.

Comment: Hi @Lgeo - I think there was an error in my answer - see revised code above. I added `path = os.path.join(root, filename)` and used `path` instead of `filename` subsequently.

Comment: it worked great thanks! Also I switched excel files for csvs because that was the other file type I need and at least that way I don't have to deal with the sheets issue.